# Namespaceless C# Code?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Every single piece of C# I have ever seen is always wrapped is a namespace.  Is it possible to include code that is not wrapped in namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to declare a specific one. Delete the namespace at the top of the script (along with the opening and closing brackets).  This will make it part of the global namespace.

From the spec:

> Namespaces and types that have no
> enclosing namespace are members of the
> global namespace. This corresponds
> directly to the names declared in the
> global declaration space.
>
> Namespaces
> and types declared within a namespace
> are members of that namespace. This
> corresponds directly to the names
> declared in the declaration space of
> the namespace.

So technically, it is part of a namespace (the global one) even though you didn't specify it.

Comment: Understand that this may not always be possible for other reasons; for instance, namespaces are used to differentiate classes with the same name, so you can't have two such classes in the global namespace. It's also generally good coding practice to use namespaces, as if everything is in the global namespace then the compiler will have to search that entire namespace for the classes you are referencing in each code file, and will present all those classes as possibilities for IntelliSense.

Comment: And i think Protected method's wont work ,they will react like Private's

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can define types in the global namespace:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have no namespace");
    }
}
```